# Generic hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, inheritance, persistence

The attached image shows what is my situation: [image]

[image]

each procedure have its own document and each document have its type.

I have lot of procedures more than 20, so more than 60 tables
for each procedure. I have to show, add, delete and update the documents related , ...
so I'm writing the same code many times 
the code is like this:

```java
 //******************list des document liés à l'étape
     Session se = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
     Criteria cr = se.createCriteria(TypeDocFinDetachement.class);
     cr.add(Restrictions.eq("step",step));
     List<TypeDocFinDetachement> list = cr.list();

     //---------------------------------------procédure fin détachement en question
     FinDetachementDAO finDetachementDAO = new FinDetachementDAO();
     FinDetachement finDetachement=null;

     if(sidFinDetachement!="")
     { Integer  idFinDetachement = Integer.parseInt(sidFinDetachement);
       finDetachement = finDetachementDAO.findById(idFinDetachement);
     }

      //*************list des document déjà scannées
       Session sess = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
       Criteria criteria = sess.createCriteria(DocumentFinDetachement.class);
       //criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("finDetachement",finDetachement));
       criteria.createAlias("typeDocFinDetachement", "t");
       criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("t.step",step));
       List<DocumentFinDetachement> listdoc = criteria.list();
       Iterator<DocumentFinDetachement> it = listdoc.iterator();
       Iterator<TypeDocFinDetachement> iterator = list.iterator();
```

I'm working in a J2EE environnment with hibernate framework.
I have to write a specific code for each procedure, 
I wonder if there is a way to generalize this?

you can refer also to this question : [Conceptual issue working with hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272729/conceptual-issue-working-with-hibernate)

Comment: Are you stuck with this table structure?  Based on what you've said here, it seems like a poor choice, sort of like having a Class per Object, instead of figuring out common elements and having several Classes and many Objects.

Comment: but each procedur has its specific column , there no relationship between them

Comment: They've got very similar relationships to 'documents', as depicted in your graph.  I'd say that could make them different instances of the same kind of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have 3 different forms of entity. E.g. for the "procedure" "FinDetachement":

- TypeDocFinDetachement
- DocFinDetachement
- FinDetachement

It's not clear why you need the 3 (obviously, reduce the number if you can).  Anyway, assuming you do need all 3...

1. Introduce a common *abstract* ancestor classes for each of "type document" and "document" and "procedure" and use @Inheritance (see [Hibernate Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#d5e3306)):

   ```
   @Entity
   @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)  // Other strategies would also work
   public abstract class TypeDocument {
        // put common document fields & methods here -
        // if you can work out what they are (they do exist - even if minor!)

        @Id
        Integer id;

        String step;

        // etc
   }

   @Entity
   @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)  // Other strategies would also work
   public abstract class Document {
        // put common document fields & methods here -
        // if you can work out what they are (they do exist - even if minor!)
   }

   @Entity
   @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)  // Other strategies would also work
   public abstract class Procedure {
        // put common document fields & methods here -
        // if you can work out what they are (they do exist - even if minor!)
   }
   ```
2. Extend these for your actual entities:

   ```
   @Entity
   public class TypeDocFinDetachement extends TypeDocument {
        // put specific fields & methods here
   }

   @Entity
   public class DocFinDetachement extends Document {
        // put specific fields & methods here
   }

   @Entity
   public class FinDetachement extends Procedure {
        // put specific fields & methods here
   }
   ```
3. Introduce a common generic DAO for JPA logic

   ```
   public abstract class ProcedureDAO<T extends TypeDocument, D extends Document, P extends Procedure> {

       public P findById(Integer id) {
           // put "procedure" query logic here
       }

       public void execProcedure(Class typeDocumentClass, 
                                          String typeDocName, 
                                          Class docClass, 
                                          String docName, 
                                          String step,
                                          String procedureId) {
           //******************list des document liés à l'étape
           Session se = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
           Criteria cr = se.createCriteria(typeDocumentClass);
           cr.add(Restrictions.eq("step",step));
           List<T> list = cr.list();
           Iterator<T> iterator = list.iterator();

           //------------------------ procédure fin détachement en question
           P procedure =null;
           if(sid != "") { 
               Integer  id = Integer.parseInt(procedureId);
               procedure = findById(id);
           }

           //*************list des document déjà scannées
           // Session sess = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
           Criteria criteria = sess.createCriteria(docClass);
           //criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(docName,doc));
           criteria.createAlias(typeDocName, "t");
           criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("t.step",step));
           List<D> listdoc = criteria.list();
           Iterator<D> it = listdoc.iterator();

           // etc
       }
   }
   ```
4. If possible, put all JPA logic into the ancestor DAO and instantiate it and call it "inline".  E.g.:

   ```
   public class SomeOtherClass {

       public void someMethod() {
           ProcedureDAO<TypeDocFinDetachement, DocFinDetachement, FinDetachement> finDetachementDAO = new ProcedureDAO();
           finDetachementDAO.execProcedure(TypeDocFinDetachement.class, "typeDocFinDetachement", DocumentFinDetachement.class, "finDetachement", "someStage");
      }
   }
   ```
5. If 4 is not possible, create extension DAOs (but only if absolutely necessary, because logic must change significantly):

   ```
   public class FinDetachementDAO extends ProcedureDAO<TypeDocFinDetachement, DocFinDetachement, FinDetachement> {

       // extend/override JPA logic here

   }

   public class SomeOtherClass {

       public void someMethod() {
           FinDetachementDAO finDetachementDAO = new FinDetachementDAO();
           finDetachementDAO.execProcedure(TypeDocFinDetachement.class, "typeDocFinDetachement", DocumentFinDetachement.class, "finDetachement", "someStage");

       }
   }
   ```