# Conceptual issue working with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, inheritance, persistence

hello i'm working on a web project with the hibernate framework 
i was dealing with this situation : i have multiple procedure , each procedure is a table , each procedure has it's own document types and its own documents

documents types is also a table which contains the list of document types related to a procedure , so it is static , each element from a specific procedure table has the same types of documents

but documents is another table which contains the list of documents that were scanned for an element from a specific procedure 
[image]

they are a lot of issues with this :

first there is no relationship between a table types document and a table procedure ; it is me when coding that i knwo logiccaly which table to use

second , with code java i'm rewriting the same code a lot of times , the same code , the only things that changes is the name of object

you can see a sample of my code here in this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189372/generic-hibernate)

i thought of the hibernate inheritance strategy , but i'm not used to work with

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189372/generic-hibernate)

Comment: i didn't have any answer nor for this neither for the other

Comment: noted, but they are the same question.  Rather than reposting the same question, you should offer a bounty (as you have on the other) and consider re-wording your question so it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write interfaces for the classes to be able to have the same logic for all entity types. Make the relation between the document type class and procedure class in code, by e.g. returning the class from a getter by the interface.

```
interface IProcedure
{
  Class getDocumentTypeClass();
}

class ProcedureOne
{
  Class getDocumentTypeClass()
  {
    return DocumentTypeOne.Class;
  }
}
```

If you need to know the class without having an instance of a procedure, you should put the relation between the classes into a kind of map.

You don't need any hibernate inheritance strategy. You can solve all this in java. The database doesn't need to know anything about it.