# static List related to Object : hibernate

Tags: hibernate

for the following situation i want to implement a more sophisticated solution
i have a table procedure , and a table list of document types related to this procedure , each 
instance of this table has the same list ,

i the relationel level ; there is no link between those two table 
there is a table procedure and a table document types  , 
i'm working with hibernate , what i want exaclty is that a list of this document will be loaded with each instance of procedure class

for example : `procedure.getListDocumenttypes()` , and this list must be static for this class

Comment: Hey, what mean by static for this class ?

Comment: static in the java sense , i don't need to instatiate an object for this class

Comment: I don't understand anything. What's a "table procedure"? What's a "table list of document types"? "related to this procedure": to which procedure? What means "each (..) has the same list"?

Comment: i have mutiliple table , table procedure_one , this table has its own document types which are the same for all the elements of this table , this types are stored in the table documents_type_procedure_one, the same thing for another table called procedure_two

Comment: you can refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272729/conceptual-issue-working-with-hibernate , the question that i posted here is one part of the big problematic

Answer (score 1):

You can use the static modifier for the List of DocumentTypes in the entity class of Procedure.

Also, please use the EAGAR fetchType, hence when the procedure loads that time only you will get the list of DocumentTypes, with static as well.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't make database entities static. They are not thread-safe. When using lazy-loading, you get real problems. Even when you turned off lazy loading, you still can't change the values in this list in a meaningful way (to change, it is important that each transaction has its own state). When it can't change, it doesn't belong to the database (just create some constants in your code).

Comment: but i need to store the types of documents in order to make it possible to modify them later by the user

Comment: you can refer to this question stackoverflow.com/questions/17272729/… , the question that i posted here is one part of the big problematic

Comment: If it is changeable data, just don't make it static.